# Is it possible to query MAPR hdfs/hive tables from Trino?

Tags: hive, trino, mapr

I am looking whether it is possible to query MAPR HDFS/Hive tables in Trino.
I can do show schemas, show tables from schemas but when I query it fails

Query 20240322_183127_00015_qjm4d failed: Failed to list directory: maprfs:/user/hive/warehouse/xx.db/xyz

trino:> exit

I have created mapr catalog connector

```
cat mapr.properties 
#Fri Mar 22 18:30:42 UTC 2024
connector.name=hive
hive.metastore.uri=thrift\://thrift_for_mapr\:9083
hive.recursive-directories=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permission issue. The show tables and such would likely to go Hive metadata catalog to be resolved. The query is when the data is actually read.

You need to figure out what user Trino is running as. Then check the permissions.

Comment: Trino cluster is running on EC2 (AWS). Trino runs as Hadoop user . While MAPR cluster is on-prim and runs as mapr user.  Do I need to configure hive.config.resources=/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml as per https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#multiple-hive-clusters